# What Windows version does software require?

Tags: windows, windows-10, compatibility

Is there a programmatic method (one piece of software would be ideal, but anything that works, works, under Windows 10) to analyze Windows software and tell what the oldest and newest  version of Windows the program will run under? Theoretically - I understand this won't have perfect accuracy no matter how it's done.

Or conversely, is there some reason besides complexity and obsolescence that it can't be done at all?

I have successfully used Depends for older-than-WinXP software, but not modern compilation and linking. Installing every OS in its own virtual machine is a bit extreme, but a potential last resort. And in most cases, no information is available about the software beyond what's in the install package (if it even has one).

Comment: Links for those unfamiliar: [depends](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) & it's more modern cousin [dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Depends (and dependencies) will tell you what DLL NAMES and being referenced via the import symbol table but not a lot more than that.  Depends WILL NOT tell you what DLLs are being loaded via "LoadLibrary()" and used through "GetProcAddress()" (a common practice).  Depends will NOT tell you if an interface has been changed to the actual library call.  Depends does not know if different versions of a library have changed ordinals for un-named functions (like MFC used).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that each Operating System comes with a set of requirements and a set of what it supports and not support.

Although programs try to be backwards compatible, there comes a point where new operating systems are fundamentally so different than the older ones, that its just not possible to support both OSses.

For example, Windows 3.1 is a 16 bit OS. Windows 95 is 32 bits but has backwards compatibility with 16 bits. In Windows XP 64 bit support was added but 16 bit support was not possible anymore, so an emulation layer was introduced which worked most of the time but not always.  In Windows 7, 16 bit support was dropped fully, etc..

Then you have things like .net Framework where newer versions are build for a specific OS and won't work on older. If an app is compiled for an old .net framework and at some point, a newer version is compiled for a newer .net framework, suddenly that app won't work on older versions of windows anymore.

Also hardware changes, and drivers typically are only made for a subset of OS versions, but not all. Manufacturers usually update drivers upto a certain date, but if a new OS comes out after that date, the drivers are not updated, and as such, that device will not work on newer OSses.

Long post short, its so complicated to get this right that you can scan for dependencies, but there never is a guarantee or foolproof way to get it. Some developers list it on their website, but even that may not always be 100% accurate.

Comment: VERY well written @LPChip.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: All useful information, nicely summarized, but a preface to my question, not an answer. In the early days of Windows, it was simple enough to statically examine a program and identify Win3.1 calls, or 98SE calls. This no longer works, for a variety of reasons you listed. My question is, is there newer technology that responds to that complexity? It's possible the answer is "no, there's not," or "yes, but don't," or "only if you're government,", or "nothing but each OS in a virtual machine."

Comment: I did not write the no that clearly, but it was meant as: no, its not possible because you never get a guarantee that you get everything.